# Optimising flot javascript in IE

Tags: php, javascript, performance, internet-explorer, flot

My client needs to use IE8. I'm using the flot graphing library and I'm hitting a limitation of the performance of javascript in IE.

When there are a thousand points the graph takes up to 10s to display. I have seen one possible [solution](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=641#c2) to speeding it up, but not sure how well this will work.

Has anyone tried optimising flot for IE?

Failing that has anyone done some performance analysis with the various PHP javascript **(not flash)** graphing libraries if there is one that will **out-perform flot** in IE8 (i.e. without canvas).

Comment: I'm starting to think that there's an interesting morality question around the effort appropriate for helping new projects deliberately targeting old versions of IE succeed.

Comment: Give it up... IE6 is quite literally garbage, and should be tortured to death with shards of old AOL cds. Do yourself a favor and go for IE8+ only. The 8/9 versions have much improved JS engines that quite literally run circles around the corpse that is IE6.

Comment: The performance is slow even in IE8 and there is a massive proportion of companies using this. I'd be happy if there was some optimisation for IE8.

Comment: I've removed the mention of IE6 as that's not the main thing.

Comment: Are you drawing point symbols on the plot (the circles for each point)?  In my experience with both Canvas and SVG javascript plotting libraries this is the most expensive operation on large numbers of points.  Your link "corrects" the speed issue by drawing the circle once and replicating it over and over.

Comment: Yes - I'm plotting canvas circles. In FF it takes the same time to draw the background and plot the points, in IE it takes 30x longer to plot the points than draw the background.  I'm going to implement the solution (mentioned in the question) of switching to using an image and see how that affects performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [jqChart](http://www.jqchart.com/). The render speed of the Line Chart is optimized for handling a large set of data.

Take a look at this sample:

http://www.jqchart.com/samples/ChartPerformance/LineChart

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). It is [compatible with IE 6](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) and the chart in this [time series demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series) has 1096 points.

I have used this library in my applications with success, although you will have to evaluate it yourself to see if it meets your performance requirements.

Comment: Not sure of the user's requirements but if you render the point symbols at each location, I'd be surprised if HighCharts wasn't slower than canvas based plotting libraries.  You'd also consume a huge amount of memory since each SVG node is part of the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Your only hope is to figure out a way to not plot all the points at once.  For instance, if you try to plot 10,000 points on a graph that is 600x300, chances are that the majority of points overlap each other almost completely.

What most people do in these situations is **pre-compute** (server-side) averages, or whatever type of aggregation is necessary, then plot that instead.  Then, use the selection plugin to allow them to zoom in on smaller areas of the graph and only there plot the complete data set for that area.